# Incorrect track size setting?

Tags: html, css

what should be the proportions of the icon path in relation to the visible area defined in the SVG element? I want to achieve an effect where the entire area around the icon's path is adjusted to it. Just like in the case of a container that would have its width set to auto (See Twitter example in the screenshot

[image]).

I have a problem that the area around the path extends beyond the SVG element and I don't know why.

```css
.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

SVG {
  display: inline-block;
  stroke: rgb(141, 145, 145);
  stroke-width: 1.4px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">
       <g>
         <path d="M 1 0 L 19 9.5 L 1 19">
       </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Give your SVG a base `width` and `height` attribute and CSS will be able to work with it. Also, consider giving it `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` to ensure compatibility.

Comment: set css of `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: What is meant by "entire area around the icon's path is adjusted to it." - the icon takes that space also or it is contained within it - your code as posted does not really look like the image referenced.

Comment: The meaning of what you put in quotation marks is self-evident. So the code looks like what? If it doesn't look like a painting? The icon has empty spaces that extend beyond the area of ​​the SVG element, nothing complicated to understand here. ;) @MarkSchultheiss